# DateTimePicker From DataGrid to Form error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Tags: c#, mysql, datagrid

When I click the DataGrid, I want to load the information back into the textboxes. All the strings load but I get an error with the DateTimePicker

```
DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex];
txtPickupLocation.Text = row.Cells["PickupLocation"].Value.ToString();
comboBxPickupArea.Text = row.Cells["PickupArea"].Value.ToString();
dateTimePickup.Text = row.Cells["PickupTime"].Value.ToString();
```

Which results in the error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

It stores in the Database as: 09 December 2013

Comment: Find out what string `row.Cells["PickupTime"].Value.ToString();` is returning.

Comment: it stores in DB as "09 December 2013"

Comment: I'm pretty sure that string won't decode into  a DateTime unless you use `ParseStringExact` with a custom format string.  Can the DateTimePicker be configured to return a more friendly date format?

Comment: That was the problem, it wasn't saving as a friendly string. I customised it to save as DD-MM-YYYY. Thanks for your help